# Groovy : String to float Conversion

Tags: groovy, floating-point

Used code below to save value for float

```
domainInstance.standardScore = params["standardScore"] as float
```

In this case my input was given as *17.9* and in db2 database saving as *17.899999618530273* but I want to save as 17.9 itself, let me know how to do it

Answer (score 6):

You can't set precision to a `Float` or `Double`  in Java. You need to use `BigDecimal`.

```
domainInstance.standardScore = new BigDecimal(params["standardScore"]).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

The method `BigDecimal.setScale(1, ...)` limits decimal to one place only. The second parameter is the rounding strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BigDecimal` to do Conversion from `String`, then `BigDecimal(value).floatValue()` to get `float`, You can do this on more that one way, examples

1 - Using `setScale` in  `BigDecimal`

```
   def temp = new BigDecimal(params["standardScore"]).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

2- Using `DecimalFormat`

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    def temp =  new BigDecimal(df.format(params["standardScore"] ))
```

Then you need to get the float value

```
domainInstance.standardScore = temp.floatValue()
```